# Create a database using Objective C read and write same database using javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, sqlite

> I have created an App in iOS using objective C and loaded the JS file for some functionality.

```
 Now the Problem is.I have created a database through objective C code.
 Want to access  the same database using  javascript.

 So can I do that?
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript is running natively then you should be able to read the SQLite database (by accessing the file and loading it into memory). All you need is access to the database and an SQLite driver.

If you're running the javascript in a WebView you might have issues accessing the local filesystem so then the answer would be no.

Comment: No javascript is not running  in WebView.Just wanna know how to open same database in javascript